# Mysql Update con inner join

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Tengo una tabla con un campo de registro de salida el cual debo modificar a @ si el valor de un campo en otra tabla es "N".

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
update tabla1 a inner join tabla2 b ON (a.codigopersona=b.codigopersona) 
SET a.registrosalida='@' where 
b.tablet='N' and a.fecha_salida between '2022-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-12-31 00:00:00';
```

Sin embargo al ejecutarlo me genera un error: `Error Code: 1442. Can't update table 'tabla2' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger.`

¿En qué parte del código podría estar el error? o ¿Cómo podría suplir el código?

Comment: Pon el codigo de tu trigger, el problema comienza ahi

Comment: Hola, realmente no estoy poniendo ningún trigger, solo ese update, es por eso que se me hace tan raro

Comment: Bueno pues parece que hay un trigger asi q revisa bien

Comment: @BrayanPulido pon SHOW TRIGGERS; y muéstranos lo que te sale editando la pregunta

Answer (score -1):

Creo que esta mal escrita la sentencia del where debe esta relaciona con la tabla2 la tabla no la veo en tu código prueba así

```
update tabla1 as a inner join tabla2 as b ON (a.codigopersona=b.codigopersona) 
SET a.registrosalida='@' where b.table2='N' and a.fecha_salida between '2022-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2022-12-31 00:00:00';
```

saludos

Comment: Tu consulta es exactamente igual a la del op, no veo ninguna diferencia en tu respuesta, revisa bien

Comment: Una referencia de tabla puede usar o no `AS`, tal como se indica en su [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html) donde dice **A table reference can be aliased using tbl_name AS alias_name or tbl_name alias_name**, por lo tanto tu consulta y la de la pregunta son iguales.